# what is the name of the font used by Walt Disney in their advertisement "Magic is here"?

Tags: fonts

The graphic designer im working with asked me to choose a Font. i really like the font used in this advertisement. however im not able to detect the font used in this video. can anyone help me with this concern ? [image]

Comment: How close does it have to be? It's not exactly an under-represented style - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhuA9.jpg

Comment: If you are looking for a similar font, then google fonts has [Outfit](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Outfit?preview.text=magic%20is%20a%20flying%20elephant&preview.text_type=custom&category=Sans+Serif,Display), which is free. It's pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

Font Squirrel says it's Averta ExtraBold based only on the letters "magic is."  Several alternatives are also offered.  https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator (There are other font matching sites listed here: https://www.schoolofmotion.com/blog/top-5-tools-to-identify-a-font)

Identifont (http://www.identifont.com/index.html) says Futura, and of the Futura styles, Futura Futuris Bold looks closest to me, but working with a *very*  small sample.

After thinking about this a bit, of the characters in the sample, the shape of the lowercase G is probably the most distinctive character in the sample.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typeface based on Futura. The one distinctive difference is that it's replaced Futura's semicircular 'c' with one that's more like three-quarters of a circle. Also, it's quite bold, so if that was what you were drawn to you want a typeface that goes up into a strongly bold weight range. Besides Averta and [Futura](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/futura-now-font-monotype-imaging) itself, something like [FF Neuwelt](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/ff-neuwelt-font-fontfont), [Futura Maxi](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/futura-maxi-font-monotype-imaging), [Mallory](https://frerejones.com/families/mallory) or [Gotham](https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/overview) might be alternatives.